# The difference between a compile/link function and a controller function in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I'm trying to write my own AngularJS directives. I think I understand the difference between the `compile` and `link` functions. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho) clears it up nicely.

But I'm not sure now that I understand the role a controller plays in a directive. A directive can include a `controller` function, and you can inject `$element`, `$attrs` and such into it, so it can do pretty much everything that the `link` function can do and, I believe, the other way around.

So I have two questions:

1. Are there important technical differences between the `controller` function and the `link` function?
2. What is best practice? What kind of work should I be doing in which?

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. Thanks! I wonder why that one didn't show up as a suggestion. I'll also vote to close.